# errorMessage: "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/task/credentials.json'" errorType: "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection"

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-oauth, google-sheets-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I am working on a Next JS app using google Sheet api for a personal project. Now this works completely fine on my local. But when I am deploying it to Netlify, this error pops up.

Can someone put up a solution?
Thanks!

*Here is my code:*

```
import { google } from "googleapis";

export default async function form1(req, res){

    if (req.method === 'POST') {
        // Process a POST request
        console.log("POST hit")
        const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
            keyFile: "credentials.json",
            scopes: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
        })

        //create client instancce
    const client = await auth.getClient();

    //instance of google sheet api

    const googleSheets = google.sheets({version: "v4", auth: client});


    const spreadsheetId = "*********55653"

    //Write rows TO sheet
    const {name, email, phone} = req.body;

    await googleSheets.spreadsheets.values.append({
        auth,
        spreadsheetId,
        range:"Subs!A:B",
        valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED",
        resource: {
            values: [
                [name, email, phone]
            ],
        }
    })

    res.send("Success")
      } else {
        // Handle any other HTTP method
        res.status(405)
      }


}
```

Comment: Did you added credentials.json file in gitignore. Check once if the file is there in netlify

Answer (score 1):

The credentials.json is the file which contains the all of the information about your google project. Without it your application can not run.

The error message `no such file or directory, open '/var/task/credentials.json'"` means that your application cant find the json key file in that directory.

Make sure that this file was uploaded to your server.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar problems, you have to manually configure it to include the `credentials.json` file in the `netlify.toml`.

For example, if you wanted your functions to use credentials.json, add this to your netlify.toml file:

```
[functions]
    included_files = ["credentials.json"]
```

You can read more about it here:
https://www.netlify.com/blog/2021/08/12/how-to-include-files-in-netlify-serverless-functions/